# Unable to signin into ebay account using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run this code to print labels for things that have sold on ebay:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\src\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk/sh/ord/?filter=status%3AAWAITING_SHIPMENT")


title = driver.title
if title == "Sign in or Register | eBay":
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("userid")
    username.send_keys("username")
    username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

However, the username does not get submitted in the text box and i can see errors in chromedriver.exe:

```
[9496:19816:0710/133749.738:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[9496:19816:0710/133751.420:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[9496:19816:0710/133751.433:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[1716] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_User_shell
```

How do i fix this and why is this happening?

Edit: This is only the sign in part of my program, i still have to find a way to print the labels.

Comment: Is this able to launch the browser and open the URL ?

Comment: @NarendraR yes, the browser launches and opens the page i wanted it to, it just doesn't input information and i see these errors in the command line for chromedriver.exe

Comment: However, ebay needs you to sign in first so it redirects you to the sign in page before allowing you to go to the awaiting shipment page ( where i wanted to go )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some simple tweaks to your code and here are is the observation:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk/sh/ord/?filter=status%3AAWAITING_SHIPMENT")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='userid']"))).send_keys("question_boi")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ebay_recaptcha]

---

### Deep Dive

When I accessed the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the website https://www.ebay.co.uk/sh/ord/?filter=status%3AAWAITING_SHIPMENT it was observed *eBay* signin page contains a script which detects [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* and user is navigated to the [recaptcha](/questions/tagged/recaptcha) verification page.

[image: ebay_recaptcha_dom]

Hence you see the error.